# Regular Expressions - Exclude characters

Tags: regex, forms, validation

I am trying to use regulare expressions with a [formvalidator.net](http://www.formvalidator.net/#reg-form) to validate a form but I am struggling to under stand regular expressions,I have had a look at some websites but it is still baffling.

Basically I want to validate a field so that when a user enter something it will chack that the word or entry doesnt contain certain characters. So for example I don't want '!name' or 'this ! name' to be accepted.

using [regexp](http://regexr.com/) for testing I have created this expression `([a-zA-Z\+\&\,\.\-\(\)\d][^<>%$!]+)` which excludes those characters but in my form validator it will still accept '!name' or 'this ! name'

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I feel like I'm typing stuff in and gettign nowhere.

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I think you want to either decide what characters you don't want **OR** what characters you do. Not both.

I think this is what your after:

```
^[^<>%$!]+$
```

[See it working here](https://regex101.com/r/eY7AOu/1)

Comment: That works! Thanks. Whats the difference though between that site you tested on and the onme I did? The one I did doesn't accept that code you entered. Just curious.

Comment: @snookian you might want to switch the multi-line flag on /m that's all

Comment: Hi again, one quick question, that code works for some characters but not for all, for example if I add # or £ after the ! those characters wont be excluded but " and = will. Any ideas?